# How to add new virtual users to an existing VSFTPD virtual user database in DB4 format?

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I have setup and configured a VSFTPD server on a Ubuntu 14.04 server that is working as intended. For authentication, I setup virtual users via a PAM passwd file in DB4 format using methodology described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd):

> Create The Virtual Users Database
>
> To create a "db4" format file to store usernames (another option here
>   would be an apache htpasswd style file, not discussed), first create a
>   plain text files with the usernames and password on alternating lines.
>   For e.g. create user called "vivek" with password called "vivekpass"
>   and sayali with password "sayalipass":
>
> ```
> cd /etc/vsftpd
> sudo gedit vusers.txt
> ```
>
> Sample output:
>
> vivek 
>   vivekpass 
>   sayali 
>   sayalipass
>
> Next, create the actual database file like this (may require the
>   db_util package to be installed first):
>
> ```
> db_load -T -t hash -f vusers.txt vsftpd-virtual-user.db
> chmod 600 vsftpd-virtual-user.db
> rm vusers.txt
> ```

My existing users work fine, but now I need to add more users to the user db file. How can I add new users to an existing vsftpd-virtual-user.db file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [man db_load](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/db_load.1.html) says:

> DESCRIPTION
>          The db5.3_load utility reads from the standard input and loads it  into
>          the  database file. The database file is created if it does not already
>          exist.

Also the option -n (Do not overwrite existing keys) might be useful.